# R make functions with lapply: bug or what?

Tags: r, lapply

I am using lapply to make new functions and noticed that that sometimes it returns what is expected, and sometimes it returns only copies of the lastly created function.

Here is an example for the illustration, consider that I want to make the following simple list of functions

```
listFuncs = lapply( 1:3, function(X){ 
  myfunc = function(y){X+y}
  myfunc
})
```

Unfortunately, a simple evaluation shows that I am not getting what I hoped

```
listFuncs[[1]](10)
[1] 13
listFuncs[[2]](10)
[1] 13
```

Indeed, the list only contains the function

```
myfunc = function(y){3+y}
```

However, if I output something during the creation of the functions, for example

```
listFuncs = lapply( 1:3, function(X){ 
  myfunc = function(y){X+y}
  print(myfunc(0)) ## NEW LINE HERE !!!
  myfunc
})
```

then my list of functions is "as expected"

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
> listFuncs[[1]](10)
[1] 11
> listFuncs[[2]](10)
[1] 12
```

Does anyone understand what is going on ? By advance, thank you.

Comment: The is not a bug, it's a feature. Study the concept of "lazy evaluation".

Comment: @Roland I was surprised by the long discussion on r-devel beginning [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-February/070686.html) that seemed to include serious consideration for the position that this is a bug (by Radford, at least). It was the first time I'd ever seen "official" folks entertain that idea.

Comment: It looks like Radford Neal and Jeroen Ooms were the only ones calling it a bug, and neither of them is official; Neal obviously understands R deeply, but he often disagrees with R-core.

Comment: @BenBolker I took Luke et al's opennes to changing the behavior (or at least discussing it) to be a tacit admission of it at least being undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [force](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/force.html) function:

```
listFuncs = lapply( 1:3, 
    function(X) { 
        force(X)
        myfunc <- function(y) { X+y }
        myfunc
    }
)
listFuncs[[1]](10) ## 11
```